# Как получить уникальные значения из двух List<T>

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс

```
public class DB
{
   public string ID{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
...
}
```

Есть два списка List. Как получить значения уникальные для обоих списков?
Для обычных List делается так

```
    var A = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4 };
    var B = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 6, 7 };

   var a= A.Except(B).ToList(); //{ 2,3,4 } 
   var b= B.Except(A).ToList(); //{ 5,6,7 }
   var abint=  a.AddRange(b);
```

Comment: у своего класса переопределите `equals` и `hashcode` методы, остальное будет идентично вашему примеру.

Comment: @tym32167: Переопределение Equals и GetHashCode не всегда уместно (например, для entity-класса, или есть класс чужой). Я бы использовал кастомный компаратор.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для обычных `List` это проще делается через [`Union`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Union__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__):

```
var a = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4 };
var b = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 6, 7 };
var ab = a.Union(b).ToList();
```

В документации к методу рассказывается как применить его к своим объектам:

> If you want to compare sequences of objects of some custom data type, you have to implement the [`IEquatable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-5.0) generic interface in a helper class. The following code example shows how to implement this interface in a custom data type and override [`GetHashCode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-5.0) and [`Equals`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-5.0) methods.

> Если требуется сравнить последовательности объектов какого-либо пользовательского типа данных, необходимо реализовать обобщенный интерфейс [`IEquatable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-5.0) в вспомогательном классе. В следующем примере кода показано, как реализовать этот интерфейс в пользовательском типе данных, а также как переопределить методы [`GetHashCode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-5.0) и [`Equals`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-5.0).

```
public class ProductA: IEquatable<ProductA>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ProductA other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        return this.Name == other.Name && this.Code == other.Code;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as ProductA);
    public override int GetHashCode() => (Name, Code).GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: `(Name, Code).GetHashCode()` — очень изящно, кстати.

Answer (score 8):

Если для чисел совершенно очевидно, что такое одинаковые числа, то для экземпляров класса `DB` это уже не так очевидно.

Если у вас в классе `DB` реализован интерфейс `IEquatable<DB>` и определены методы `Equals` и `GethashCode`, то скорее всего ваше равенство объектов совпадает с равенством по `Equals`, и вы можете воспользоваться реализацией как в ответе default locale.

Но что делать, если вы не можете или не хотите реализовать `IEquatable<DB>`? Например, ваш класс может принадлежать 3rd party-библиотеке, или быть DTO-классом, в котором реализация интерфейсов не имеет особого смысла? Менять реализацию класса ради одного создания списка не очень-то и правильно, тем более что вам может в другом месте понадобиться `Equals` по другим свойствам.

В этом случае придётся разобраться, что же для нас *равные* экземпляры.

---

По умолчанию равными считаются просто совпадающие экземпляры. Например, если вы создадите

```
var o1 = new DB { ID = "1", Name = "Вася" };
var o2 = new DB { ID = "1", Name = "Вася" };
```

то `o1` и `o2` не будут считаться равными, равными будут считаться только совпадающие объекты. Если вам нужно именно это, то можно использовать `a.Union(b).ToList()` без всяких изменений.

---

Если же ваши объекты пришли, например, из базы данных, то для вас скорее всего равными являются те объекты, которые имеют одинаковый `Id`. Для таких целей вам нужно сравнивать объекты *по `Id`*.

Как это сделать? Можно воспользоваться [перегрузкой `Union`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Union__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__), которая принимает *внешний* компаратор типа `IEqualityComparer<DB>`, в который вы и передадите свой компаратор для именно этого случая.

Такой компаратор можно написать вручную:

```
class DBComparer : IEqualityComparer<DB>
{
    public bool Equals(DB x, DB y) => x is null ? y is null : string.Equals(x.ID, y?.ID);
    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] DB obj) => obj?.ID?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
}
```

и ваш код будет таким: `a.Union(b, new DBComparer()).ToList()`.

Можно написать более общий компаратор, который можно будет повторно использовать:

```
class ProjectingComparer<T, TF> : IEqualityComparer<T> where TF: IComparable<TF>
{
    readonly Func<T, TF> projection;
    public ProjectingComparer(Func<T, TF> projection) => this.projection = projection;

    public bool Equals(T? x, T? y)
    {
        IComparable<TF> px = x is null ? null : projection(x);
        IComparable<TF> py = y is null ? null : projection(y);
        return px is null ? py is null : px.Equals(py);
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] T obj) =>
        obj is null ?
            0 :
            (projection(obj)?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
}
```

и ваш код будет таким: `a.Union(b, new ProjectingComparer<DB, string>(db => db.Id)).ToList()`.

В будущем .NET 6 появится [метод `UnionBy`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27687), который будет делать именно то, что нам нужно, так что ваш пример запишется просто как `a.UnionBy(b, db => db.Id)` без всяких вспомогательных конструкций.

А прямо сейчас можно воспользоваться пакетом [`MoreLinq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), в котором хоть и нету метода `UnionBy`, но есть метод `DistinctBy`, при помощи которого легко реализовать нужную функциональность: `a.Concat(b).DistinctBy(db => db.ID).ToList()`.

Кстати, `DistinctBy` несложно написать и самому:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> seq,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    var keysSoFar = new HashSet<TKey>(keyComparer);
    foreach (T t in seq)
    {
        // Add возвращает false если такой элемент уже есть
        if (keysSoFar.Add(keySelector(t)))
            yield return t;
    }
}
```

---

Ещё один (менее эффективный) метод сэмулировать `DistinctBy` — использовать `GroupBy`: `a.Concat(b).GroupBy(db => db.Id).Select(g => g.First())`.

---

А что если вы хотите задать равенство не по одному полю `Id`, а по нескольким? В принципе, работает тот же подход, просто будут другие лямбды, ведь вы можете объединить несколько значений полей в одно при помощи кортежей. Получится `a.Union(b).DistinctBy(db => (db.ID, db.Name)).ToList()` или там `a.Union(b, new ProjectingComparer<DB, (string, string)>(db => (db.ID, db.Name))).ToList()`. Ну и класс `DBComparer` можно переписать очевидным образом.

Comment: Даже не знал, что Вы вернулись на сайт, с возвращением! Как всегда исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: @defaultlocale: Я ненадолго. Но спасибо, что помните.